# Set up a bidirectional relationship between dog and owner (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I am very new to programming and I'm working on an assignment for a dog auction program, where i want to write a method to give a dog to a person.

I have an owner class, where I want to store dog objects in an array (I know using a list is an option, but the assignment specifies the use of an array). I have a dog class, where I want to be able to set an owner.
The problem I have is that I want to automatically set the dogs owner variable whenever I add the dog to the owners array of owned dogs, and vice versa, i want to automatically add the dog to the array if i call the setOwner method in the dog class

This is my dog class:

```
public class Dog{
    private String name;
    private String breed;
    private int age;
    private int weight;
    private double tailLength;
    private Owner owner;

    public Dog(String name, String breed, int age, int weight) {
            this.name = name;
            this.breed = breed;
            this.age = age;
            this.weight = weight;
            
    }
   
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public String getBreed() {
        return breed;
    }
    
    public void increaseAge() {
        age++;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public double getTailLength() {
        if (breed.equalsIgnoreCase("dachshund") || breed.equalsIgnoreCase("tax")) {
            return 3.7;
        } else {
            return weight * (age / 10.0);
        }
    }
    
   public Owner setOwner(Owner owner){
    return this.owner = owner;
   }
   
    public Owner getOwner(){
        return owner;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name + " Breed: " + breed + " Age: " + age + " Weight: " + weight + " Tail length: " + getTailLength();
    }

}
```

This is the owner class:

```
public class Owner {
        
        private String ownerName;
        public Dog[] dogList = new Dog[1];
        
        public Owner(String ownerName) {
            this.ownerName = ownerName;
        }
        
        public String toString(){
            return "Name: " + ownerName;
        }
        
        public String getName(){
            return ownerName;
        }            
    
    }
```

Finally, this is the giveDog method so far:

```
public void giveDog(){
        System.out.print("Enter the name of the dog?>");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        Dog dog = findDog(name);
    
    if (dog == null){
        System.out.print("Error: No dog with that name");
    return; 
    }
   
    if (dog.getOwner() !=null){                    
        System.out.print("Error: Dog already has owner");
    return; 
    }

         System.out.print("Enter the name of the new owner?>");
         String nameOfOwner = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();
         Owner o = findOwner(nameOfOwner);

         if (o!= null) {
            
            dog.setOwner(o);
            owner.dogList[0] = dog;
        

         


             System.out.println(owner.getName()+" now owns "+ dog.getName()); 


         

         } else {
             System.out.print("Error: No such owner");

        } 
     }
```

What change(s) could I make to my code so that adding a dog to an owner or vice versa sets the other automatically?

Answer (score 1):

First I'd suggest using a List instead of an array. It's much simpler to add and remove items.

At present the code for setting the ownership is:

```
  dog.setOwner(o);
  owner.dogList[0] = dog;
```

What change do you think you could make to `Dog.setOwner()` so that you didn't need to do `owner.dogList[0] = dog;` after calling it? That is, putting some code in `setOwner` so that you could just say `dog.setOwner(o)` and both directions of the relationship would be established?

Setting the relationship the other way is not so easy -- you are giving the Dog to the Owner by directly manipulating a data structure which is inside the Owner object, instead of calling a method. This means that you have nowhere to put code to create the other direction of the relationship. So creating an `Owner.addDog` method is a good idea.

Finally, once you start setting the bidirectional relationship in both places you'll need to think about avoiding an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest
Change your `Owner.dogList` to be a list instead of an array.
Change `Dog.setOwner()` to:

```
public void setOwner(Owner o) {
    if(this.owner != o) {
        this.owner = o;
        o.getDogList().add(this);
    }
}
```

And just call `dog.setOwner(o);` in your `giveDog()` method.

Comment: A list would be simpler and I would like to use one, but the assignment specifies that an array should be used instead

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

Firstly, Modify `setOwner` method in that not only sets Owner but all assign dog to the owner

```
class Dog {
    private String name;
    private String breed;
    private int age;
    private int weight;
    private double tailLength;
    private Owner owner;

    ...

    public Owner setOwner(Owner owner) {
        owner.assignDog(this);
        return this.owner = owner;
    }

    ...
}
```

Secondly, create `assignDog` method in `Owner` class

```
class Owner {

    private String ownerName;
    public Dog[] dogList = new Dog[10];
    private int dogCount = -1;

    ...

    public void assignDog(Dog dog) {
        this.dogList[++dogCount] = dog;
    }

    ...

}
```

Finally, you can call `setOwner` which will set the bidirectional relationship

```
public class Solution {

    public static List<Dog> dogs = Arrays.asList(new Dog("Tom"));

    public static List<Owner> owners = Arrays.asList(new Owner("ALICE"));

    public static Dog findDog(String name) {
        for (Dog dog : dogs) {
            if (dog.getName().equals(name)) {
                return dog;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static Owner findOwner(String name) {
        for (Owner owner : owners) {
            if (owner.getName().equals(name)) {
                return owner;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the name of the dog?>");
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        Dog dog = findDog(name);

        if (dog == null) {
            System.out.print("Error: No dog with that name");
            return;
        }

        if (dog.getOwner() != null) {
            System.out.print("Error: Dog already has owner");
            return;
        }

        System.out.print("Enter the name of the new owner?>");
        String nameOfOwner = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        Owner o = findOwner(nameOfOwner);

        if (o != null) {

            dog.setOwner(o);
            System.out.println(o.getName() + " now owns " + dog.getName());

        } else {
            System.out.print("Error: No such owner");

        }
    }
}
```